# dir command not working in a specific folder

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, ssd, cmd.exe

```
C:\Users\Shailesh\My Documents>dir
 Volume in drive C is XXXXXXXX     \\never seen these two lines before
 Volume Serial Number is XXXX-XXXX

 Directory of C:\Users\Shailesh\My Documents

File Not Found
```

dir command is working when I use it on C:\Users\Shailesh

I recently cloned my data to a new internal ssd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in the "dummy" Special-folder `My Documents` of Windows 7 (which is empty).

Try doing `dir ..\Documents` and you will see your documents.
(or `cd ..\Documents` followed by a `dir`).

Windows 7 changed the `My Documents` to `Documents`. In the explorer it is still named `My Documents` but that is only a 'display-name'. It is language dependent. In a dutch version it is `Mijn Documenten` but (on the harddrive) it still points to `Documents`.

For older programs who still expects a `My Documents` this directory is created and under Windows it is redirected to `Documents`. However you are in a command prompt which does **not** do this redirection.

I don't know how you got into this directory in the prompt but you should have done a `cd Documents` instead of a `cd My Documents`.

You can read [here](https://wiki.carleton.edu/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/9961710) what other directies are changed. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_folder) for information about "Special folders".

Answer (score 3):

The command is working fine – "File Not Found" is normal when `dir` does not have anything to show.

This happens when directory has either the "Hidden" or "System" attribute (causing `dir` to skip displaying the `.` and `..` items), and is either empty or all files/subdirectories have such an attribute as well (causing those files/subdirectories to be skipped as well).

Answer (score 0):

Try `attrib -s -h *.*` before calling `dir` , or try `dir /a`.